# Row height difference

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

When I try to get the row height the returned value varies from the height in the spreadsheet. I have the row height for row 5 set to 10 but when I use the code;

```
Sub RowHeightTest()

    MsgBox Rows(5).Height

End Sub
```

it returns 9.75 if I change the height to 20 I get 19.5, why is there a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
Sub RowHeightTest()

    MsgBox Rows(5).RowHeight

End Sub
```

Yours gives me the same issue, mine works fine for me.

**Make sure you're using ROWHEIGHT, not HEIGHT.**

[excel showing row height set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwzPS.png)

Yours:
[Your non-working answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGceT.png)

Mine:
[My working answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZZNo.png)

Comment: Same incorrect result, did it work for you?

Comment: @Naz yes it works for me, I added picture proof to the answer. Please re-read my full answer as I believe your issue is Height vs RowHeight

Comment: `MsgBox Rows(1).RowHeight` also works. Your problem is using Height instead of RowHeight. Please accept this answer once you can confirm.

Comment: This answer is correct.

Comment: My bad didn't notice the RowHeight.

Comment: @Naz all good, not sure what the difference is, I'm sure it's real row-height (ROWHEIGHT) versus available row content height (HEIGHT) or something silly like that. This occurs in other languages too, such as C#.